# unset multiple variables with array_walk()

Tags: php

I'm trying to unset multiple variables using `array_walk()`.  Here's my code:

```
$remove = ['module', 'file', 'data', 'route'];
array_walk($remove, fn(&$v) => unset($v));
```

However, this results in the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'unset' (T_UNSET) in C:\files\develoment\OrdersApp\config.php

I know there are other approaches to unsetting multiple variables but it seems like `array_walk()` ought to be able to do it.  Why is the presence of `unset()` in the code above causing a parse error?  How should it be modified so it works?

Comment: Or just `$remove = [];` for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#:%7E:text=Only%20the%20values%20of%20the%20array%20may%20potentially%20be%20changed%3B%20its%20structure%20cannot%20be%20altered%2C%20i.e.%2C%20the%20programmer%20cannot%20add%2C%20unset%20or%20reorder%20elements.%20If%20the%20callback%20does%20not%20respect%20this%20requirement%2C%20the%20behavior%20of%20this%20function%20is%20undefined%2C%20and%20unpredictable.)

> Only the values of the array may potentially be changed; **its structure cannot be altered**, i.e., **the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder elements**. If the callback does not respect this requirement, **the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable**.

```php
$remove = ['module', 'file', 'data', 'route'];

$limit = sizeof($remove);
for($i =  0; $i < $limit ; $i++){
    unset($remove[$i]);
}

var_dump($remove);
```